Extend asterisk next to close/delete vote to flags
We recently got an asterisk (*) next to the close and delete vote to indicate you've already voted on that question/answer:

Why is there an asterisk next to the close vote total? E.g. Close (1*)
Make it clearer when looking at a question if I've already voted to close it
Make the "delete" button different when you already voted to delete



Could we extend that to the flags as well?
Currently only the popup indicates if you already flagged that question.


The reason we didn't implement this at the same time as the other button changes was because the Flag button doesn't show the number of Flags like vote to Close/Delete — which has it's own reasons that would be worth considering for this. This and the Flag modal make the logic a bit different than the other buttons (a bit of extra work in making this change). We decided to leave it out for now since the possibility of making an error in retracting wasn't as likely as the other buttons.

@0stone0 can you imagine what a disaster it would be when users start complaining that there are flags to their posts? They are already complaining about votes, close votes, and delete votes. But moreover, what does a number of flag really show? A user might have raised a flag in lieu of a close vote (because they don't have the CV privilege). Or they might have raised a spam flag. How is the number "1" help when it could be either? There can be flags that are nothing to do with a quality of a post, too. A mod flag to notify about something that's not "the post/user is bad" in any way.

Makes sense @VLAZ, didn't think about it that way, thought about a flag privilege, but that doesn't exist ofc. Still a * (without a count) if you flagged it seems quite useful.

I agree it's useful. I just think flags being private is a good thing. I use the Advanced Flagging userscript and it adds a little flag to the post when you've flagged something.  https://i.sstatic.net/AJQ6U668.png

@Carrott that's worthy of an answer, and a [tag:status-deferred] tag, IMO.
